# Is UInt8 in Swift really the equivalent of uint8_t from C

Tags: c, swift, types, swift2

I was wondering if `UInt8` is really the equivalent of `uint8_t` from C.

I'm trying to write the same application in C and Swift.

In C I've got

```
uint8_t hello[] = { 0x60, 0x60, 0xB0, 0x17 };
```

while I wrote

```
var hello = [UInt8](count:4, repeatedValue: 0);
hello[0]  = 0x60;
hello[1]  = 0x60;
hello[2]  = 0xB0;
hello[3]  = 0x17;
```

But when I use them in my socket based application they do not seem to be handelt equally. And also the XCode Debugger shows different data for both variables.

C:

[image: Debugger output for the variable in C]

Swift:

[image: Debugger output for the variable in C]

So my question is how can I achieve the same result in Swift than I did in my C code or is this really the same type of data?

Comment: The C display is showing the values as character constants, the Swift display is showing the values as decimal. The two sets of values are identical. Try right clicking on the variable name. There should be a menu item that allows you to change the display format.

Comment: It's just a minor problem with the debugger. `uint8_t` in C is equivalent to `char` so the the debugger must have thought it was a character. And sure enough, character `0x60` in the ASCII table is the backtick. What do you get when you right-click the value and select Show as hex?

Comment: If I change the display format in my C program to `decimal` it shows exactly the the same numbers as in the Swift debugger output. But XCode seems to have problems converting the Swift variable in another display format. Anyway it is good to know that this seems not to be my point of failure. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

In C, uint8_t is not a really a type , it is a redefinition of something that's fit in 8 bits
Usually it is char, (character ASCII)
So you C debugger just translate your 8 bit data into characters according to the ASCII table  . Have a look at the table , you will find where your characters displayed come from.
In swift, it sound it understand real 8 bits value, and your debugger display integer in 8 bits values , which are signed by the way, which is odd

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, `hello` is actually bridged as a `UInt8` tuple (`(UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)`):

[image: Bridged]

Where its values can be accesed by 0, 1, ...

[image: Array]

I would try with the tuple format rather than a Swift array of `UInt8` types, if you can.